# How to turn off warning messages from php local host

Tags: php, localhost

when a query doesn’t match e.g user name and password, the localhost returns an warning message. how can i turn it off?

i think there is some 
Can someone guide me please?

waning message is this

```
Warning: mysql_result(): Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 2 in /var/www/login/loginform.php on line 24
```

Comment: A little bit of advice: Rather than turn it off, fix your code so it doesn't throw the warning.

Comment: Can you post your `loginform.php` ?

Answer (score 1):

Edit your PHP.ini file :

Set these two lines as :

```
   display_errors = Off
    display_startup_errors = Off
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should fix whatever's causing the warning, but you can hide / show errors with error_reporting. To hide warning messages, you could use something like this:

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must fix your code rather turning it off.
If you want to off warnings you can set it in php.ini of your server. Set

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

I recommend doing this globally is not a good idea. So do it in your project using PHP. To do this you can use PHP function

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

Put this function before where your code starts execution.